# What do I do about 429 Unknown Error on EC2 AWS server using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, amazon-ec2

```
url = "websiteExample/.json"

readLines(url, warn = F)
```

**Output:**

```
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'websiteExample/.json'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open URL 'websiteExample.json': HTTP status was '429 Unknown Error'
```

If I do this on an EC2 box in R - I immediately get that error. I don't get it after hitting a bunch of times. It's on the first try. I tried doing another instance and it still didn't work.

Comment: This is an indication that there are too many requests - and one request from the wrong IP may be too many.  There is no way for us to know the answer as the target website sets the rules.  Have you contacted the website owner and asked them what the restrictions are?

Comment: Someone has posted: requests.get(link, headers = {'User-agent': 'your bot 0.1'}) that fixes for Python. Do you the equivalent for R. Can't seem to feed headers. Also, locally my IP works, but the EC2 one doesn't. Does the site then know it came from Amazon?

Comment: It looks like you need to pass a `headers` parameter when you create the connection.  And yes, depending on the site it's very possible that the site is blocking Amazon IP addresses.

Comment: There is no headers parameter in readLines that I see, do you know how to pass it?

Comment: It's in the `con` object.  When you create that you can pass headers.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind giving an example of how to do that, unclear to me the syntax?